# Native crash in Google ML Kit Face Detector module

Tags: android, google-mlkit

We have started receiving these reports recently, around 25th Jan. There was not App Update pushed, since this module is updated by Play Services itself, I highly suspect it has something to do with it.

Title in the Play Store says "[dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk] com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetectorV2Jni.d"

Below is a stacktrace (package name is changed to com.example):

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000002d6d64  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #01  pc 0x00000000002ba5d7  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #02  pc 0x0000000000419b6b  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #03  pc 0x00000000002bb991  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #04  pc 0x00000000002aef8d  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #05  pc 0x00000000002ac4b1  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #06  pc 0x000000000043b291  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #07  pc 0x00000000004361e3  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #08  pc 0x0000000000274f6d  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #09  pc 0x000000000026f20b  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #10  pc 0x0000000000271c4f  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #11  pc 0x0000000000270f2d  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #12  pc 0x0000000000270899  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #13  pc 0x00000000001027c1  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #14  pc 0x00000000001025db  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #15  pc 0x0000000000102539  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #16  pc 0x00000000001017e9  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk
  #17  pc 0x00000000000d88dd  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+44)
  #18  pc 0x00000000000d3dd5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #19  pc 0x00000000004f93f1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+280)
  #20  pc 0x000000000012c49f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+142)
  #21  pc 0x000000000024094f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+250)
  #22  pc 0x0000000000238e57  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+746)
  #23  pc 0x00000000004ecce9  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+512)
  #24  pc 0x00000000000ce914  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #25  pc 0x0000000000044e66  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk (com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetectorV2Jni.d+10)
  #26  pc 0x00000000004ead5b  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1290)
  #27  pc 0x00000000000ce814  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #28  pc 0x00000000000483c8  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk (mk.h+320)
  #29  pc 0x00000000004ecf43  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1114)
  #30  pc 0x00000000000ce914  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #31  pc 0x0000000000047848  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk (mk.b+148)
  #32  pc 0x00000000004ead5b  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1290)
  #33  pc 0x00000000000ce814  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #34  pc 0x000000000006feea  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk (asl.a+90)
  #35  pc 0x00000000004ead5b  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1290)
  #36  pc 0x00000000000ce814  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #37  pc 0x0000000000031360  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/000000d1/dl-VisionFace.optional_230313100300.apk (bp.onTransact+40)
  #38  pc 0x0000000000231c0f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.11360311041479653056)+250)
  #39  pc 0x00000000002385c3  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+114)
  #40  pc 0x00000000004dc129  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+684)
  #41  pc 0x00000000000d8961  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
  #42  pc 0x0000000000606d5b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Binder.transact+114)
  #43  pc 0x00000000000d3dd5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #44  pc 0x00000000004f93f1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+280)
  #45  pc 0x000000000012c49f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+142)
  #46  pc 0x000000000024094f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+250)
  #47  pc 0x0000000000238e57  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+746)
  #48  pc 0x00000000004ec1c5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+876)
  #49  pc 0x00000000000cea14  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #50  pc 0x0000000000be41b2  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_face.zza.zzb+14)
  #51  pc 0x00000000004f0b89  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1180)
  #52  pc 0x00000000000d2594  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
  #53  pc 0x0000000000beb840  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_vision_face.zzoy.zzd+22)
  #54  pc 0x00000000004f0b89  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1180)
  #55  pc 0x00000000000d2594  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
  #56  pc 0x0000000000f69eb2  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zza.zzh+144)
  #57  pc 0x00000000004ed767  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1046)
  #58  pc 0x00000000000ce994  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #59  pc 0x0000000000f69c30  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zza.zza+98)
  #60  pc 0x00000000004ec459  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1536)
  #61  pc 0x00000000000cea14  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #62  pc 0x0000000000f6a40c  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zzh.zze+32)
  #63  pc 0x00000000004f0b89  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1180)
  #64  pc 0x00000000000d2594  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
  #65  pc 0x0000000000f6a3dc  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.vision.face.internal.zzh.run+4)
  #66  pc 0x00000000004f0b89  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1180)
  #67  pc 0x00000000000d2594  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
  #68  pc 0x0000000000678056  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.MobileVisionBase.zza+22)
  #69  pc 0x00000000004f0b89  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1180)
  #70  pc 0x00000000000d2594  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
  #71  pc 0x0000000000f68d8e  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.zza.call+8)
  #72  pc 0x00000000004ec459  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1536)
  #73  pc 0x00000000000cea14  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #74  pc 0x0000000000f637ae  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.ModelResource.zza+74)
  #75  pc 0x00000000004f0b89  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1180)
  #76  pc 0x00000000000d2594  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
  #77  pc 0x0000000000f671b6  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzn.run+20)
  #78  pc 0x00000000004ec459  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1536)
  #79  pc 0x00000000000cea14  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #80  pc 0x0000000000f67246  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzt.run+20)
  #81  pc 0x00000000004ec459  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1536)
  #82  pc 0x00000000000cea14  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #83  pc 0x0000000000f6359e  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zze+26)
  #84  pc 0x00000000004ed767  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1046)
  #85  pc 0x00000000000ce994  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #86  pc 0x0000000000f63558  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzc+16)
  #87  pc 0x00000000004ed767  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1046)
  #88  pc 0x00000000000ce994  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #89  pc 0x0000000000f670ea  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzk.run+4)
  #90  pc 0x0000000000231c0f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.11360311041479653056)+250)
  #91  pc 0x00000000002385c3  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+114)
  #92  pc 0x00000000004dc129  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+684)
  #93  pc 0x00000000000d8961  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
  #94  pc 0x0000000000242bef  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+1014)
  #95  pc 0x000000000024040f  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+54)
  #96  pc 0x00000000000d3dd5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #97  pc 0x00000000004f93f1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+280)
  #98  pc 0x000000000012c49f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+142)
  #99  pc 0x000000000024094f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+250)
  #00  pc 0x0000000000238e57  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+746)
  #01  pc 0x00000000004ec1c5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+876)
  #02  pc 0x00000000000cea14  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000f63578  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.MlKitThreadPool.zzd+20)
  #04  pc 0x00000000004ed767  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1046)
  #05  pc 0x00000000000ce994  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000f6709e  /data/app/~~jgbeqlWNgv-PvyoA_5RM3A==/com.example-msd8digxT3qWyCdmhyLm7Q==/oat/arm/base.vdex (com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.zzi.run+4)
  #07  pc 0x0000000000231c0f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.11360311041479653056)+250)
  #08  pc 0x00000000002385c3  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+114)
  #09  pc 0x00000000004dc129  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+684)
  #10  pc 0x00000000000d8961  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
  #11  pc 0x000000000012fc01  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+64)
  #12  pc 0x00000000000d3dd5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #13  pc 0x00000000004f93f1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+280)
  #14  pc 0x000000000012c49f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+142)
  #15  pc 0x0000000000404d91  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+372)
  #16  pc 0x0000000000404e9f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+42)
  #17  pc 0x00000000004475df  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1090)
  #18  pc 0x00000000000aadbb  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+40)
  #19  pc 0x0000000000063bcd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
```

**SDK Info:**
com.google.android.gms:play-services-mlkit-face-detection:17.1.0

**Other statistics:**
Spread across many android devices, but mostly running Android 11.
There are 12.6K event reports for this, impacting 1.34K users, in last 7 days.

How do I solve this, would really appreciate if someone have any leads.

Answer (score 0):

the same error started to appear Jan 22 on production, and it occurs on devices with Spreadtrum chipsets (mainly USC9863A) and the
Imagination Tech PowerVR GPUs. I also think that downloading models through google play services may have something to do with that, and I will try using the bundled version of the library instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed in Google Play Services whose version >= 2309XXX